# como Acceder a una ruta de un controller sin que necesite autentificación?

Tags: mvc, spring-boot, jwt, oauth2

Estoy utilizando Spring Security, Jwt y Oauth2 con arquitectura mvc.Necesito acceder a una ruta en mi controller sin que me pida autentificación, utilizo la anotación `@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})`

```
   @RestController
@RequestMapping("/personas")
public class PersonasController {
@Autowired
private PersonasService personasService;


@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
@PostMapping("/add")
public int create(@RequestBody Personas per) {
    return personasService.create(per);
}
```

quiero acceder a este método Post dado a que los tokens solo se generan cada vez que un usuario ingresa al sistema, pero, si hay una persona que quiere crearse un usuario no se le permite porque no tiene autorización de un token. Mi SpringSecurityConfig se encuentra asi:

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .csrf().disable()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

}

ya intenté con utilizar `.antMatchers("/personas/add").permitAll()` alguien me puede decir si sirve la anotación `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` para dar acceso anónimo o algo parecido?

Comment: ya has usado la regla del `antMatchers("/personas/add").permitAll()` en conjunto con `@PreAuthorize(permitAll())` ?

Comment: no, pero me fincionó con esto ```@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServiceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
 @Override
 public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/personas/add").permitAll()
  .anyRequest().authenticated()
  .and().cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
 }```

Comment: y mi controller sin el ```@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})```